This code changing the image as expected but not the id?


const currentTypesResult = [{
  id: '155',
  foodId: '511555522559744444',
  image: 'Some image string',
  example: 'example'
}]

const processedResults = currentTypesResult.map((item) => {

  const {
    foodId,
    image,
    ...rest
  } = item;

  return {
    id: '5542',
    image: 'data:image/png;base64,',
    ...rest
  };
});

console.log(processedResults[0].id) // Prints 155? Why? Why not 5542?
console.log(processedResults[0].image) // Prints data:image/png;base64, (AS IT SHOULD)



I'm expecting id to change from 155 to 5542 when I print processedResults[0].id (It prints the old value 155) just like image was changed from some image string to data:image/png;base64, when I printed processedResults[0].image

In your map function, you're using the spread operator ...rest to include the remaining properties of the original object (item). However, since id is part of the rest object, it overwrites the id: '5542' that you set earlier. The ...rest spreads all the properties that were not destructured, including id, which is why id: '155' from the original object ends up in the final object.

Simply, remove the ...rest from your code lines, it will work fine.

currentTypesResult.map(({foodId, image, ...rest}) => ({...rest, id:"5542", image:"data:image/png;base64,"}));

You need to put the rest before the id property otherwise the id will get overwritten since it is already a part of the rest. Here is the working code example:


const currentTypesResult = [
  { id: '155', foodId: '511555522559744444', image: 'Some image string', example: 'example' }
];

const processedResults = currentTypesResult.map((item) => {
  const { foodId, image, ...rest } = item;

  return {
    ...rest, 
    id: "whatever you like",
    image: 'data:image/png;base64,'
  };
});

console.log(processedResults[0].id); // Now it should print 'whatever you like'
console.log(processedResults[0].image); // Should print "data:image/png;base64,"




I edited  your post to include your script in the live code snippet. You can use this feature by hitting the <> in the "Answer" dialog window.
